# Migrate local server database info to remote web server after adding language or storefront

Tags: database, mysql, importexport, local

I have a Magento local install for testing. How do I transfer my database changes after I add e.g. a new language.

I have added all the products texts etc pp, but I can't just dump the mysql database back because, it would delete all the orders made during my translation, what is the best modus operandi, in such case?

Answer (score 2):

You could export all products form the local server, and then import all of the products onto the production server.

Some linkes with details:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/import_export/export_tool
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/using-import-export/

Comment: If this resolved your problem, be sure to mark the question as answered.